# Objective C - Encryption with AES256 GCM

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, encryption, aes-gcm

Currently I'm using the below method for Encryption

```
+ (NSData*) encrypt:(NSData*)plainText key:(NSData*)key iv:(NSData*)iv {
    NSUInteger dataLength = [plainText length];
    size_t buffSize = dataLength + kCCBlockSizeAES128;
    void *buff = malloc(buffSize);
    
    size_t numBytesEncrypted = 0;
    CCCryptorStatus status = CCCrypt(kCCEncrypt, /* kCCEncrypt, etc. */
                                 kCCAlgorithmAES128, /* kCCAlgorithmAES128, etc. */
                                 kCCOptionPKCS7Padding, /* kCCOptionPKCS7Padding, etc. */
                                 key.bytes, kCCKeySizeAES256, /* key and its length */
                                 iv.bytes, /* initialization vector - use random IV everytime */
                                 [plainText bytes], [plainText length], /* input  */
                                 buff, buffSize,/* data RETURNED */
                                 &numBytesEncrypted);
    if (status == kCCSuccess) {
        return [NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:buff length:numBytesEncrypted];
    } else {
        // Encryption Failed
    }
    
    free(buff);
    return nil;
}
```

I need to use now AES256 GCM for encrypting, I don't see `kCCAlgorithmAES256` in `CCCrypt`. Someone please guide me, I'm using the framework `pod 'RNCryptor-objc'`.

Below is the decrypt logic handled in backend.

```
public static byte[] decrypt(byte[] key, byte[] data) {
// TODO utilize GCMAES#decrypt method
try {
  if (data.length < NONCE_LENGTH + TAG_LENGTH) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("data packet too short");
  }

  int cipherTextLength = data.length - NONCE_LENGTH - TAG_LENGTH;

  byte[] nonce = Arrays.copyOf(data, NONCE_LENGTH);

  GCMBlockCipher cipher = new GCMBlockCipher(new AESFastEngine());
  AEADParameters parameters = new AEADParameters(new KeyParameter(key), TAG_LENGTH * 8, nonce);
  cipher.init(false, parameters);

  byte[] out = new byte[cipher.getOutputSize(cipherTextLength + TAG_LENGTH)];

  int pos = cipher.processBytes(data, NONCE_LENGTH, data.length - NONCE_LENGTH, out, 0);
  pos += cipher.doFinal(out, pos);

  return Arrays.copyOf(out, pos);

} catch (IllegalStateException | InvalidCipherTextException ex) {
  throw new IllegalArgumentException(ex);
}}}
```

Comment: If you read Rob's update on `https://github.com/RNCryptor/RNCryptor-objc` he explicity states: `If there were a good authenticated AES mode on iOS (GCM for instance), I would probably use that for its simplicity.  I'd rather the complexity at a more broadly peer-reviewed layer like CommonCryptor than at the RNCryptor layer. But this isn't an option, so I fall back to my own Encrypt-than-MAC.`  Maybe you can do the same?  `AES-CTR + HMAC` recommended here: http://www.daemonology.net/blog/2009-06-24-encrypt-then-mac.html

Comment: There is no built-in GCM implementation for ObjC. Since iOS 13, there's CryptoKit for Swift, and you could wrap that into an ObjC module, but I'm (still) not aware of any easy-to-integrate GCM module for ObjC. You wind up needing to build it yourself or use OpenSSL, which is difficult. I've built these often for clients, but I don't know a simple answer that is open source without switching to Swift.

Comment: Thanks @RobNapier for your response, the backend decryption functions like my UPDATED Question, do you've any suggestions for that?

Comment: Yes, you either need to implement it by hand, or use OpenSSL. I've done this a bunch of times for clients. It's not particularly easy, but it's doable. I don't know of any open source solution for this that drops into ObjC. The other way is to wrap a Swift solution, like CryptoKit (or CryptoSwift). You can also wrap C or C++ implementations. But I don't know any ObjC implementations that are open source.

Comment: Thanks Rob, could you please provide any encryption code snippet for this Rob.?

Comment: Look at https://github.com/indisoluble/AesGcm. I've never explored that package, but it may work. If that doesn't work for you, I am happy to discuss on a consulting basis (rob@neverwood.org), but this is too large a project for a Stack Overflow answer. Best of luck with your project.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I've seen that pod and exploring it Rob. Will get back.